# Rollout of responsive design site themes - Tracking post

Tags: discussion, design, announcements

This post will be updated as the responsive design and left navigation layouts are released on each site.

Previously, we tried this out by [releasing still screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes) of the site designs and getting input on them and then releasing them live. This was problematic because users couldn't actually interact with the sites and we'd get feedback on several sites in one place, which was more difficult to follow. It also meant the sites were public with some bugs that didn't show up in testing.

We decided to revamp this process when we released the design for Photography and created a way to let users opt-in to preview the site design before it was live to everyone. Joe talks more about this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314542/opt-in-to-beta-testing-new-themes). This gives us the chance to make bug fixes *before* we release the designs to everyone.

**To give feedback on these designs:** follow the link below to that site's child meta post announcing the design.

**To give feedback on responsive design and left navigation:** refer to either [this existing post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness) or, for more history on the process, [this older one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes).

**To read our explanation for these changes:** review [Why we initiated the latest round of design changes and the role of meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314799/why-we-initiated-the-latest-round-of-design-changes-and-the-role-of-meta). If you have any feedback for how we can do better at keeping you informed, let us know there.

---

### Live for everyone:

- [Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4299/academias-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13097/arqades-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing) (Gaming)
- [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1404/something-new-coming-to-the-artificial-intelligence-stack-exchange)
- [Ask Different](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/ask-different-new-site-theme-is-live) (Apple)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18114/ask-ubuntu-new-site-theme-is-live)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8960/code-reviews-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6688/electrical-engineerings-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4941/giss-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Information Security](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3065/information-securitys-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28842/mathematics-new-site-theme-is-live)
- [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4755/mi-yodeyas-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing) (Judaism)
- [Music: Practice & Theory](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3061/musics-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Photography](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5756/photography-new-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10784/physics-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320/updated-theme-with-left-navigation-is-live-for-quantum-computing)
- [Role-playing Games](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8391/role-playing-gamess-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9347/server-fault-new-site-theme-is-live)
- [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8802/software-engineerings-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- Stack Overflow
- [Stack Overflow in Japanese](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2783)
- [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7324)
- [Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3677)
- [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7907)

  - [MSE post regarding the Language-specific SO sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315856/responsive-design-for-international-sites-has-been-released)
- Meta Stack Exchange
- ["Stock" theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315662/responsive-design-coming-to-all-beta-undesigned-sites-soon?cb=1) (beta and non-designed sites)
- [Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13242/super-user-new-site-theme-is-live)
- [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7781/tex-new-site-theme-is-live)
- [Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4824/travels-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4923/unix-linux-new-site-theme-is-live)
- [Web Applications](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4582/web-applications-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6744/15896)
- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2442/android-enthusiasts-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Ask Patents](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383/ask-patents-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Aviation](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/aviation-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Bicycles](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1304/bicycles-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Biology](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3873/biology-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Blender](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/blenders-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4314/chemistrys-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/christianitys-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Computer Science](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1515/computer-sciences-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cross-validateds-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Cryptography](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1102/cryptographys-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Database Administrators](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/dbas-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3726/drupals-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Emacs](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/541/emacs-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11693/english-language-usages-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [English Language Learners](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4826/english-language-learners-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [ExpressionEngine® Answers](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1327/expressionengine-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Game Development](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/game-development-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3545/graphic-design-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Home Improvement](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/home-improvement-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Japanese Language](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1908/japanese-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Magento](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/magento-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Mathematica](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/mathematica-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3976/mathoverflow-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Movies & TV](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4370/movies-tv-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824/network-engineering-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/personal-finance-money-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Puzzling](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6495/puzzling-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/raspberry-pi-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Salesforce](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/salesforce-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12073/science-fiction-fantasys-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/seasoned-advice-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing?cb=1) (Cooking)
- [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/sharepoint-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing?cb=1)
- [Signal Processing](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1618/signal-processing-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Skeptics](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4280/skeptics-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2801/software-recommendations-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/8111/stack-apps-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3025/theoretical-computer-science-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [User Experience](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3295/user-experience-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing?cb=1)
- [Webmasters](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1592/pro-webmasters-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4518/wordpress-developments-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- [The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/the-workplace-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)
- Area 51 ([discussion zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/))

Comment: Part of the motivation for standardizing layouts was to make it easier to provide custom themes for sites that don't currently have one.  Yet it seems all of the sites in this post currently have a theme.  When do you expect to provide new custom themes to unthemed sites?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom After the existing site layouts are updated, all of the network will have the unified design (the beta theme will be rolled out to all undesigned sites eventually) and then we'll start working on the sites with no design. We need to get the baseline in place before we roll out entirely new designs.

Comment: [es.so],[ja.so],[pt.so],[ru.so],[russian.se] aren't mentioned. Why?

Comment: @Rubén it could be that unthemed sites are not listed. [portuguese.se] isn't listed either.

Comment: @ANeves: I made a mistake on one of the smart links, instead of [russian.se] it should be [rus.se] which is unthemed but the other four sites are themed.

Comment: @Rubén To be honest, it's because I'm not sure what the plan is for them. I'm guessing they'll eventually get the same design as SO, so technically they're "complete" but not rolled out, but they're not getting Teams, as far as I'm aware, so they're not really "finished" since that module is excluded. I'm checking on it and will update when I have an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I hope that the new theme(s) will not bring "new" localization issues (i.e. usually Spanish requires larger strings / text boxes). Also I hope that the themes will not be the same in order to help to minimize posts on the wrong language)

Comment: @Rubén We're testing them internally and will probably be rolling them out live (not in testing) on Thursday or Friday. We're not making new themes, just reworking the existing ones, so they're getting the same as SO, which they've had for a while, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Thank you for the update and for including these sites on the list :)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @ChristianRau :) As a note, if I forget, y'all are more than welcome to edit it. ;)

Comment: @Catija - I don't see Mechanics listed anywhere ... what gives?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 This list has all of the beta/default theme sites together as they share the same layout. Only sites with custom designs are listed individually.

Comment: @Catija - Makes sense ... that's probably spelled out somewhere and I didn't see it. My apologies :o)

Comment: It would be useful to add what exactly determines the transition between the beta testing and live phases. For example, I have the impression that ELU has been in the beta phase for a time longer than that of the other sites.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano There's not an actual... "policy"... As you can probably tell, we haven't actually switched any over to live for everyone in a while. We're going to start doing that now that everything is in testing. ... but mostly it's a judgement call. If the bugs that have been reported are generally fixed, or there aren't any complaints, the site goes live for everyone. If there are major bugs or unaddressed issues, it stays in beta until we can fix them.

Comment: Is there a post for MSE itself, for incidental issues?

Comment: @curiousdannii it's probably easiest to ask a new question. You can alternatively put it here but it may get a bit lost: [Live: Left nav, new theming and responsiveness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness)

Comment: Area 51 Discussions appears to have a responsive design rolled out. Can you please update your post?

Comment: I'm not following SE much of late. My question is why am I not seeing the new design in any site? E.g., in Super User, I am seeing just plain white theme, no theme color at top or bottom, no design at top. Same goes to Server Fault.