# Flagging a message by a moderator resulted in a suspension from another moderator

Tags: discussion, chat, moderators, account-suspension, chat-flags

What can a person do if they flagged a chat message posted by a moderator that is spam, inappropriate, and/or offensive, and then another moderator suspends that person that flagged the original moderator's message? Additionally, the person sent a message to the Stack Exchange team, but they refused to do anything.

Comment: Note: This question relates to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28869/350198) answer; specifically what to do when those options don't work.

Comment: It would probably be better to add this as an answer to that question.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314981/how-could-i-have-handled-this-better-in-chat-flag-apparently-led-to-suspension)?

Comment: @TheWanderer I thought if an answer to a question doesn't answer my question, I was to ask a new question?

Comment: @JennaSloan You're also supposed to explicitly indicate in your post that you're aware of that question and explain why its answer didn't help.

Comment: To be clear: neither Shog nor Cat are moderators. They are Community Managers, employees. Even if Cat’s message was all-capped strong (shouty) it wasn’t hate speech or trying to sell you something, so the flag certainly should’ve been declined. Other than that there may be context missing, I wasn’t there, but there was probably more going on there.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Oh, well I didn't know that. Sure would be nice if it said that somewhere. Perhaps you could edit this question?

Comment: I feel like you're leaving out a big chunk of this story.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog No. That's not correct. If the flag is currently active, the moderators on the site where the room is parented can see who cast the flag.

Comment: @JennaSloan It's outlined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not), and linked from the FAQ on duplicates. The system also prompts you if someone votes to close as a duplicate. (I decided to let you know in advance of casting a duplicate vote.)

Comment: @Catija Huh, I was wondering why Shog said he had to query the database to figure out who flagged the message in question.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog because the flag was no longer active, presumably.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was involved in the situation (I was one of two users suspended as a result of flagging that message, the author of that post is the other), and I felt it was a violation of the Code of Conduct, specifically the provision that users shouldn't be disrespectful. I've commented on Shog's (downvoted) answer as to why I thought so.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I understood that. Not sure why you are telling me that, actually.

Comment: @JennaSloan anywho, the correct answer is to do what Robert did; to politely ask for clarification on Meta about the specific situation.

Comment: @Shog9 Which story? I've seen this happen so many times that if I added specific details from any of those stories it would make the question inadequate. Please note that this particular question is about moderators, not the Stack Exchange staff. Also, I honestly have no idea what situation Martijn Pieters was referring to.