# What is the dispute surrounding my 2018 chat suspension question?

Tags: support, specific-question, locked-questions, post-notices

My old question [How could I have handled this better in chat (flag apparently led to suspension)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314981/336163) from September 2018 has, within the last hour, been locked, unlocked, locked, unlocked, and then locked again by a moderator. It currently has a post notice that "There are disputes about this question’s content being resolved at this time".

This lock reason is traditionally used for edit wars, but the history of the question shows only one recent edit, and that touches on grammar only. I can see no evidence of any current edit dispute or vandalism, copyright violation, hate speech, or any other similar content that typically draws moderator action.

*What is currently in dispute over my question, and what must be done to get it unlocked?*

To be clear, I do *not* wish to rehash the subject matter of my question. I am asking why the question needs to be locked now and under what criteria it could be unlocked. The purpose of that question was never to seek closure over what had happened at the time, but to find a resolution that we could all learn from and apply in the future to prevent future problems. If there are further edits that can help emphasize that, I would be open to them.

Answer (score -7):

It's from 2018. It's been closed and opened a few times and has had waaaaay too much drama around it. Circumstances as such that it needs a wee bit of a cool down.

As for the locking and unlocking.... I apparently fat fingered it a few times. That's on me.

Comment: The only recent activity around it is a grammar edit - no recent reopenings or re-closures, or other types of drama, in its history (or that of any of the other answers). Also, no evidence of a "content dispute". If all the activity it had in August was from today or yesterday, the lock would make sense, but the fact is, it was months ago. Why does it need to be locked down now?

Comment: Also, if you really want the question to be locked, why not remove the incorrect notice (assertion) that there's a content dispute, so that it's just locked?

Comment: Simply cause it's the one that fit the best.  And there's obviously activity. Else I wouldn't have bothered.

Comment: Isn't it possible that you can manually remove the post notice while keeping the question locked? The assertion that there's a "content dispute" is incorrect.

Comment: Why else do you think the post was getting locked and unlocked?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense...if that was the case, why didn't you just say that in your answer, instead of calling it a "fat-fingering"?

Comment: Did someone flag the post? It only surfaced on the home page because of a minor edit, made by a different user not the OP. But I did see the question  had garnered three reopen votes, was that it? Is that the evidence of contention?

Comment: Its exactly the circumstances as they happened. That question had a *remarkable* amount of drama in the past surrounding it.  I have a rough idea of how to deal with it. Considering its an issue that was addressed, over a year ago, digging it back up probably doesn't do much good.

Comment: Considering that the user who provoked much of the drama at the time is currently suspended, I wouldn't have worried too much about potential future drama as a result of that edit, and only dealt with it if it actually ended up happening again.

Comment: and I don't think waiting for that seems prudent. Least from what I see. I think a lock seems like a less painful solution

Comment: @JourneymanGeek less painful but probably the easy way out instead of a real solution.