# Locking a question as a "content dispute" is incorrectly locking the answers and hiding the vote buttons, like "historical" and "obsolete" locks

Tags: bug, status-completed, locked-questions, locked

In other words, "content dispute" locks are now [freezing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) questions instead of [locking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) them.

Per the second link above, locks on questions for reasons other than "historical significance" and "obsolete" are supposed to only disallow interactions with the question while the answers remain unlocked and interactable. [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314981/how-could-i-have-handled-this-better-in-chat-flag-apparently-led-to-suspension) was locked with the "content dispute" reason before this bug came up, and it is working as designed there.

However, it appears that the behavior meant only for "historical" and "obsolete" locks is now applying to questions locked as "content disputes": the answers are being locked and the  vote buttons are being hidden on the question and all answers (even though the latter should still be able to be voted on with this type of lock):

[image: Voting buttons on question hidden even though it's only locked as a "content dispute"]

[image: The answer's voting buttons are hidden too]

This doesn't seem to happen for "wiki answer" locks (which are meant to impose identical restrictions as "content dispute" locks); it *only* happens for "content dispute" locks.

Can this please be fixed? I think this may have happened because the menu was programmed to impose this type of lock on specific indexes in the locking menu, and the order was changed and indexes weren't updated to reflect the change.

Comment: Yeah, there was a content dispute on an answer on Ask Different about a month ago and the answer is still locked... :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've fixed this issue - it was due to a bug where we updated a specific check without making sure that change didn't have unintended effects in other places where that check was used. Please let me know if you still have any issues, and, as always, thanks for the report!

Comment: Do posts have to be unlocked and re-locked before the fix takes effect?

Comment: @Laurel I don't believe so - are you still seeing an issue?

Comment: Yes, there's [this meta post](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4984/197614) which is missing vote icons. Several other posts were locked around the same time but still have vote icons, maybe because they are all answers.

Comment: @Laurel Thanks for the example, after looking into it a bit more closely it does seem that we only update the "frozen" status when we make a change to the lock. For this particular post I'm going to just remove the lock.