# How can I find out if I voted on a post with historical lock?

Tags: support, voting, locked-questions, historical-lock

Other than laboriously going through my votes in my profile, is there any way to know if I voted on a post where the vote arrows are missing due to a lock?

[image: no vote icons]

In this case it's a content dispute ([apparently a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389926/323179)), but the same applies for historical locks.

Comment: Ordinary locks won't remove the vote buttons, afaik only historical lock removes them. Anyway, don't think there is a way to know if you voted, except a userscript.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard The screenshot is from a [content dispute](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4984/197614).

Comment: Huh, weird. I will look into it, but saw several locked posts having the vote arrows just fine.

Comment: @Laurel Looking at the linked bug report, it's marked as [tag:status-completed], with an answer stating it's fixed, so if you're still seeing that bug, that may be worth noting, either in another answer or via a follow-up bug report

Comment: Your profile has pages with lists of all the posts on which you voted, separated into upvotes and downvotes. Why is that not sufficient? Given that the post isn't deleted, you should also be able to get the data as to if you voted from the SE API. I'd expect that it's also available from the SE internal endpoints which provide vote information for the post, but I haven't checked.

Comment: @cocomac As per the comments there, the fix was not retroactive - that is, posts that were affected by the bug will have to be unlocked and re-locked to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this through the SE API. The [question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question), [answer](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer), and [post](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/post) types have both a `downvoted` field and an `upvoted` field which, respectively, show if the requesting user has upvoted or downvoted the post. That information is considered private, so you will need to [obtain](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) and use an `access_token` when making the request for the data on the posts.

I say "should be able to do this", because I have not actually tested that the data is valid, due to the difficulty in finding an appropriately-locked post which I know I've voted on in order to verify the `upvoted` and `downvoted` data is provided accurately. However, I'd consider it unlikely that a filter would have been put on the data provided by the SE API for the cases of a posts locked with specific types of locks.