# Will Area 51 Discussions be getting a responsive design?

Tags: support, area-51, responsive-design

It's been said already that due to the age of Area 51's code base, it will not be affected by the upcoming design changes. However, the Area 51 *Discussions* site runs on a more modern code base, the same one that powers the rest of the sites.

However, I noticed that in the [tracking post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314979/rollout-of-responsive-design-site-themes-tracking-post), it's not listed as a remaining site. Are there plans on giving it a responsive design, or will it continue to run with the original design even after all the responsive designs fully roll out?

Please note that this isn't a request asking that it get a responsive design; this is a neutral question.

Comment: uh... if aliens think we were improved than them, they may stop coming to A51

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep. It's coming up - last but not forgotten.

It's on the same base as the rest of the network other than Area 51 itself, so it's getting an update. It's important to note that - as you say, Area 51 is a special case and will not be updated in this process.

It's been added to the tracking post and should be updated sometime soon.