# Area 51 navigation bar doesn't display properly in half-window mode

Tags: bug, status-review, area-51, user-interface, top-bar

When in half-windowed mode, the [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) top navigation bar's dark blue background breaks on the right side of the screen, showing the text over the background image, in Firefox and Chrome.

[image: Buggy Navigation Bar UI]

Comment: I wouldn't assume Area 51 has all the responsive gizmo's you'll find on SE proper ... it is a bug but be prepared for no-fix.

Comment: @Kewal FWIW, mine is a tiny bit different, perhaps related to screen width (FF Android desktop mode): https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CfDW.jpg

Comment: Related/dupe: [Will Area 51 Discussions be getting a responsive design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316118)