# Some sites' review pages are now poorly wrapped, resulting in wasted space and a scrollbar

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design, stackapps

**Update** from Shog9:

> Also affects Aviation, Cooking... Probably everything on the "not yet in progress" list here: [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314979/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314979/rollout-of-responsive-design-site-themes-tracking-post) - I've passed this on to the devs. – Shog9

---

The [Stack Apps review page](https://stackapps.com/review) got busted in the last few hours.  It looks ugly and now needs to be scrolled, see below.

Other review pages ([EG 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review), [EG 2](https://stackoverflow.com/review)) are still fine. And the problem appears for me in both Chrome and Firefox -- and whether or not I'm logged in.

> [image: bad layout]

versus:

> [image: good layout]

Comment: Also affects Aviation, Cooking... Probably everything on the "not yet in progress" list here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314979/rollout-of-responsive-design-site-themes-tracking-post - I've passed this on to the devs.

Comment: Also seen on Science Fiction and Fantasy, which is on the beta-testing in progress list.

Comment: Also affects graphic-design and movies&TV

Comment: Can second SFF, MTV and ELU.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed for the time being; the original change was made to allow more space for localized text that was running into the next section:

[image: review page prior to original change on Russian Stack Overflow]

...unfortunately, making this column wider left less space for the (fixed-width) second & third columns on sites that haven't yet been updated with a responsive design.

The long-term fix here will be to completely redesign this page, allowing it to use as much space as is available... But for now, the text in the first column will simply be truncated if it grows too long:

[image: review page on Russian Stack Overflow *now*, with long translation truncated]

Thanks to Aaron & Jane for tackling this!