# Counter's text is truncated in queue on localized sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, localization

SOru:

> [image]

SOes:

> [image]

Can you fix it? It looks very ugly. Make it flexible, or, at least, increase `width` of `.dashboard-item .dashboard-count`.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317618/some-sites-review-pages-are-now-poorly-wrapped-resulting-in-wasted-space-and-a - fixing this will require a substantial redesign of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aaron completely redesigned this page with a responsive design that adapts smoothly to different translation lengths and screen sizes:

[image: animation of the page reflowing as I reduce page width]

Comment: Yeh, we saw it and already had few issues with it (: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8499/15479