# Why am I now unable to click on comments/achievements links to questions from an Android phone (on sites where I have an account)?

Tags: support, comments, achievements-dialog, android

Back in the day, SE used to work just as well on a phone browser and on a laptop.

Then some time ago I found that **from an SE site** I couldn't click on the links that show up when you click on the car window in the up right corner next to your badge count:

[image]

Or when you click on the star cup next to the car window:

[image]

**BUT** I still could click on them from the main site, https://stackexchange.com/

So I got into the habit of taking a sneak peek into hot questions with my morning coffee.

Now the feature is broken even from the main site: I can click the car window to get an overview of comments, but I can't click on a particular comment - the same goes with achievements.

Is my phone really just getting old? I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S2 for the record.

---

I just found out that everything works perfectly *on SE sites where I do not have an account*. On the sites where I'm active, even clicking the icons won't show the lists now. On the main site, it's halfway: I will see the list but I can't click on the items.

Comment: The "car window" (good likeness!) is supposed to represent an [in tray](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1309&bih=647&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ACYBGNSUCXnclTWGAou--AJBIgvvVqYl4g%3A1575651147842&sa=1&ei=S4fqXZn2MofKwAL33pqIAQ&q=in+tray.&oq=in+tray.&gs_l=img.3..0i7i30l2j0i7i5i30l2j0i30l6.8585.8585..9258...0.0..0.86.242.3......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i10i30.SRbcvf3kLJQ&ved=0ahUKEwjZx9P3vaHmAhUHJVAKHXevBhEQ4dUDCAc&uact=5#imgrc=3WXeWDkdvYmGqM:). +1 for "car window" image description, I cannot unsee it now.

Comment: The [Pinto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1EVN.jpg) sized [inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wllce.jpg). BTW: Works OK for me on FF Android.

Comment: @Mari-LouA & Rob Thanks for the good laugh I had at your comments :) I've updated the question as I figured out the behaviour is quite different on sites where I have an account.

Comment: [Morris Mascot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini) (also featured in [Fawlty Towers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fawlty_Towers) (which episode?)).

Comment: Doesn't it work in pure web mode (by virtue of [responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314979) and all that)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm using the built-in browser, I'm not aware of any such options.