# Meta logo appears too high in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: bug, design, meta, internet-explorer

On Internet Explorer 11, the "Meta" logo in the top appears too high:

[image]

On Microsoft Edge, it renders correctly:

[image]

It used to render correctly in IE; what's changed?

Comment: At some point they replaced whatever CSS hacks that kept the logo middle aligned with a `display: flex;` rule, which is [only partially supported by IE11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). (Without this rule, it looks the same in Chrome too.) All in all, I'm afraid fix isn't trivial so I doubt it will ever be fixed, IE has very low usage.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Agree. Why give up the convenient flex box for the sake of supporting IE?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because IE is no longer supported and this request is unlikely to be implemented since a lot of IE-specific code was removed today, breaking a lot of core functionality.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Internet Explorer is no longer supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322637/maybe-its-time-to-formally-drop-support-for-ie-11).